# Query String ID for ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my .aspx page I have an href:

```
<a runat="server" href"~/petstore.aspx?pageID=1">Dog Store Page</a>

<a runat="server" href"~/petstore.aspx?pageID=2">Cat Store Page</a>
```

I have a database of Dog/Cat items to be displayed based on the pageID.

How can I call the pageID based on whether the user clicks on "Dog Store" or "Cat Store?

I tried (in my aspx.cs page):

```
string page = "";

page = Request.QueryString["pageID"];
```

But it doesn't seem to fetch the ID :(

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is the **rendered** HTML for those links?

Comment: Is that `Request.QueryString["pageID"]` returns null or empty string? And what kind of anchor markups are rendered?

Comment: Was something lost when pasting into your question? This HTML is not valid: <a runat="server" href"~/petstore.aspx?pageID="+2> You want something like <a runat="server" href="~/petstore.aspx?pageID=2">

Comment: Yeah, sorry. <a runat="server" href="~/petstore.aspx?pageID=2">....I need the pageID for a parameter to load the information from the database.

Comment: What is the rendered URL, i.e. what URL do you end up on when you click the link?

Comment: Figured it out. It was a logic error on my part :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's better if you use two asp LinkButtons and have separate click event handlers each as shown below:

.aspx

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="CatLinkButton" runat="Server" OnClick="CatLinkButton_Click" Text="Cat Store Page" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="DogLinkButton" runat="Server" OnClick="DogLinkButton_Click" Text="Cat Store Page" />
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void CatLinkButton_Click(...) { // Do logic }
protected void DogLinkButton_Click(...) { // Do logic }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<a href="/petstore.aspx?pageID=1">Dog Store Page</a>
<a href="/petstore.aspx?pageID=2">Cat Store Page</a>
```

OR:

```
<a runat="server" id="aDog">Dog Store Page</a>
<a runat="server" id="aCat">Cat Store Page</a>
```

+ in code behind:

```
aDog.Href = "/petstore.aspx?pageID=1";
aCat.Href = "/petstore.aspx?pageID=2";
```